# Can I replace my mountain bike's back wheel quick release?

Tags: quick-release

I was wondering if there is a way to replace my bike's rear quick release with something which would be harder for someone to steal.

At the moment all that someone has to do is pull the leaver and they can take my wheels, so I just wanted something which is safer and can be opened when needed with something like an allen key or something.

Comment: If you're able to park your bike in a safer place, will be better overall.  Your bike could have QRs on both wheels, and on the seat clamp.  Some caliper brakes  have QRs to add slack, for removing a wheel, and Cantilever brakes have straddle cables that can be unhooked.   There's a lot of vulnerable areas of your bike, so safer parking is easier overall.

Comment: Locking the wheels to the frame is a good solution since it provides a visible deterrent and won't inconvenience you when you need to fix a puncture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There are many, many products exactly as you describe, with mechanisms ranging from simple hex keys to actual locks. A web search for "theft proof quick release", "anti theft skewer" or something like that should find some of them.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it. i was looking all day and couldn’t find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the wheel we're talking about it's "just a wheel" and not anything fancy, you can use a cable tie to attach the quick release lever to the fork/frame; it ovioubsly doesn't prevents "serious" thieves from steal your wheel but it's better than nothing.